# Is $\ \{x(t) \in L^1[0,1] \mid 0 \le x(t) \le t^2\} $ a compact in $ L^1[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

In my functional analysis class I was given a problem:

*Is* $\ \{x(t) \in L^1[0,1] \mid  0 \le x(t) \le t^2\} $ *a compact in* $ L^1[0,1]?$

$L^1[0,1]$ is Banach space and I know that subset of a Banach space is compact if and only if it is closed and totally bounded. And also I know that for banach spaces totaly bounded is equivalent to relative compactness. So I need to check if my subset is closed and relatively compact or not. But I don’t understand how to do this by definition. In our lectures we proved criterions of relative compactness for some banach spaces (for example: $l_2$, $C[a,b]$), but haven’t proved and even discussed criterion for $L^p[0,1]$, where $p \geq 1$.

Nevertheless, in the functional analysis exercise book of professors of my deparment I found a criterion for relative compactness for $L^p[0,1]$ which was proved by Kolmogorov (1931) and M. Riesz (1933):

*Set $M$ in* $L^p[0,1], \ 1 \leq p < \infty$ *is relatively compact if and only if and only if*
$\ \forall\varepsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta>0 \ \forall x \in [0,1] \ \forall h \in [0,\delta] $
$$ \displaystyle \left (\int \limits_0^{1-h} |x(t+h)-x(t)|^p dt \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq \varepsilon $$

But we haven’t discussed this theorem, so it is better to solve this problem by definition. But I will be grateful if you give me a source where the proof of this theorem is written.

So I appreciate any hint about how to solve this problem using only definitions and criterions which I mentioned in the second paragraph.

Comment: @daw You missed absolute value or square for $\sin$ function.

Comment: Please edit the title.. It seems to say "Does there exist a cmpact suset of $L^1[0,1]?"$, which is not what you meant.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yes, the sequence should be $x_n(t) = t^2 \sin^2(2n\pi t)$.

Comment: @daw i can't understand why iti s countrexample. i know that compactness in our case (of hausdorf spaces) is equivalent to two facts 1) that every infinite sequence in our subset has a limit point in our subset 2) that every infinite sequence in our subset has subsequence which converges in our subset. i've calculated $\|x_n(t)\| = \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{16\pi^2 n^2}$. But it doesn't give anything. So I think I should check one of the equivalnces above in this comment. But this nontrivial for me. Can you explain, please, why this sequence is a counterexample?

Comment: @EvgenyRomanov: The usual criteria for compactness in L_p is the [Kolmogorov-Riesz theorem](https://www.math.ntnu.no/conservation/2009/037.pdf)

Comment: Is @daw's sequence in your set?  Does it have a limit point?