# Why $x_n(t) = t^2 \sin^2(2 \pi n t)$ does not converges in $ \{x(t) \in L^1[0,1] \mid 0 \le x(t) \le t^2\} \subseteq L^1[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Yesterday I asked [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4581591/763588) about compactness of  $ X:=\{x(t) \in L^1[0,1] \mid  0 \le x(t) \le t^2\}$ in $L^1[0,1]$. @daw said in the comments that, in his opinion, it is not compact and the sequence $x_n(t) =  t^2 \sin^2(2 \pi n t)$ should give a counterexample.

I know that in our case compactness of $X$ is equivalent to the fact that every infinite sequence in this subset converges in $X$. So to prove that  $X$ is not a compact by using sequence above I should prove that this sequence does not converges in $X$.

I tried to prove this by successful lower estimate of $\|x_n(t)-x_m(t)\|_{L^1} = \int \limits_0^1t^2|\sin^2(2\pi nt)-\sin^2(2\pi mt)|dt$, but I haven't succeed: all inequalities I  get are not what I need.

I will appreciate any hints about how to prove that $x_n(t) =  t^2 \sin^2(2 \pi n t)$ does not converges in $X$.

Comment: The point is not so much whether $\{f_n\}$ converges or not but whether there is a convergent subsequence (compactness would imply convergence along a subsequence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int \limits_0^1t^2|\sin^2(2\pi nt)-\sin^2(2\pi mt)|dt=\frac{1}{2}\int \limits_0^1t^2|\cos(4\pi nt)-\cos(4\pi mt)|dt\ge$$$$\ge\frac{1}{2}\int \limits_{1/2}^1t^2|\cos(4\pi nt)-\cos(4\pi mt)|dt\ge\frac{1}{8}\int \limits_{1/2}^1|\cos(4\pi nt)-\cos(4\pi mt)|dt\ge$$$$\ge\frac{1}{16}\int \limits_{1/2}^1|\cos(4\pi nt)-\cos(4\pi mt)|^2dt=\frac{1}{32}.$$
Here we used that $\dfrac{|\cos(4\pi nt)-\cos(4\pi mt)|}{2}\le1$ and then $$\dfrac{|\cos(4\pi nt)-\cos(4\pi mt)|}{2}\ge\dfrac{|\cos(4\pi nt)-\cos(4\pi mt)|^2}{4}$$

Comment: (+1) You arguments implies that no subsequence of $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ (in the notation of the OP) converges.